# Log File over 400gigs...need to bring this database back to life

Tags: transaction-log, restore

I'm not a dba so I don't understand the admin side of SQL Server too much.  One of our sharepoint instances blew up and our IT staff asked if I could assist bring it back to life.  I found backups for sharepoint which is great.  The thing about sharepoint is it is huge with many many databases.  I have recovered all but one database (Sharepoint_Config).  This database Sharepoint_Config's log file is over 400 gigs large!

Remember this database is currently "disconnected" have you, meaning I do not have access to it via sql management studio, its just a physical ldf file and an mdf file.  We have software that we use that can restore these physical files back to their original location.  So that part is simple, however I do not want to restore an ldf file that is over 400 gigs large.

Is there anything I can do to fix this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like no one took log backups on that database for a very long time.  Restore the MDF and try:

```
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname='YourDB',
@physname=N'C:\Path\To\YourDb.mdf'
GO
```

Then set up regular backups for those databases, both full and log backups.  [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179478.aspx) is an article on log backups that might help.  [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx) is a more general article on SQL Server backups.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Katherine, I will try this out in about 10 minutes, waiting for the completion of some other databases but I will report back.  Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12367/discussion-between-katherine-villyard-and-jonh)